# mute media key doesn't toggle

Tags: audio, keyboard, xbindkeys

Logitech K270 has media keys:

- play/pause
- mute/unmute
- volume down
- volume up
- home
- mail
- power
- calculator

I don't know what "home" is supposed to do, whereas "mail" and "calculator" don't do anything simply (I hope I'm not wrong) because I haven't installed a calculator and a mail client yet.

But: "mute/unmute" only mutes.

As a workaround I've tried to put the following two lines

```
"pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle"
  XF86AudioMute
```

in the `.xbindkeysrc` file, but the key kept muting the audio, so I mapped

```
"playerctl previous"
  XF86AudioMute
```

and it still kept muting, just like the mapping I'm using is overridden or simply not working.

Finally, as a dirty workaround I've used the following two lines

```
"pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle"
  shift + XF86AudioMute
```

which works, but requires one more keystroke.

I've tried with other keys, and it seems that `xbindkeys` cannot map media keys without a modifier (ordinary keys work just fine even without).

**EDIT 1**

By the way, I think I'm pretty confused on the argument (audio). For instance, system volume is a think, the volume set in the player is another. How to control the former? And the latter? What if I bind the same key to both?

**EDIT 2**

When I run `xbindkeys -n` in a terminal, I get

```
$ xbindkeys -n

*** Warning ***
Please verify that there is not another program running
which captures one of the keys captured by xbindkeys.
It seems that there is a conflict, and xbindkeys can't
grab all the keys defined in its configuration file.
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was wrong in saying that play/pause and volume up/down keys were working since the beginning, I just forgot having put the following lines in `~/.config/i3/config`

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer -q set Master 5%+ unmute
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer -q set Master 5%- unmute
bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec playerctl play-pause
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec amixer -q set Master mute
```

where the last line is wrong, and was overriding the `.xbindkeysrc` setting.

Now I have to decide wether to put all settings in the `i3` config file or in `xbindkeys`'s file.

In either case the above solves my original issue.